# Android ListView adapter doesnt show items properly

Tags: android

Below is my listview adapter which doesnt show the items when i click an item to jump to the next activity and come back after. The data are received from a Database.

```
public class CropSelectionActivity extends Activity implements
        android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = CropSelectionActivity.class.getName();
    private static CropsAdapter listAdapter;
    private static ListView listView;
    public static String selectedCrop = null;
    private static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private static PendingIntent pendingIntent1;
    private static AlarmManager alarmManager1;
    private static final long SYNCALARAMINTERVEL = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final long DELETIONINTERVEL = 15 * 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaypoints);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Log.i(TAG, "----onCreate()-----");
        fireAlarm();
        final String details[] = DALAccessLayer.getUserMailAndId(CropSelectionActivity.this);
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setTitle("Esap Expert"+"("+details[1]+")");
        actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listAdapter = new CropsAdapter(this,R.layout.listview);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();

        Map<String, Integer> list = DALAccessLayer.getCrops(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseConstantsString.status_unresolve.getValue(), "0");
        int pointsCount = 0;
        for (String key : list.keySet()) {
            CropPojo cp = new CropPojo();
            cp.setCropName(key);
            pointsCount = pointsCount+list.get(key);
            Log.i(TAG, "pointsCount ="+pointsCount);
            cp.setCount(list.get(key));
            listAdapter.add(cp);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        Log.i(TAG, "number of existing points ="+pointsCount);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        listAdapter.clear();
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        CropPojo cp = (CropPojo) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        selectedCrop = cp.getCropName();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayPoints.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.logout:
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            case R.id.refresh:
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.getexpertporfile:
                CommunicationHandler.getExpertProfile(getApplicationContext());
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

```js
public class CropsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropPojo>{

 private int textViewResourceId;
 
 public CropsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId);
  this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final View view = getWorkingView(convertView);
  final ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(view);
  final CropPojo cropPojo = getItem(position);
  viewHolder.titleView.setText(cropPojo.getCropName());
  viewHolder.locationView.setText(String.valueOf(cropPojo.getCount()));
  return view;
 }

 private View getWorkingView(final View convertView) {
  // The workingView is basically just the convertView re-used if possible
  // or inflated new if not possible
  View workingView = null;
  
  if(null == convertView) {
   final Context context = getContext();
   final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   
   workingView = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, null);
  } else {
   workingView = convertView;
  }
  return workingView;
 }
 
 private ViewHolder getViewHolder(final View workingView) {
  // The viewHolder allows us to avoid re-looking up view references
  // Since views are recycled, these references will never change
  final Object tag = workingView.getTag();
  ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
  
  
  if(null == tag || !(tag instanceof ViewHolder)) {
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   
   viewHolder.titleView = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
   viewHolder.locationView = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.location);
   
   workingView.setTag(viewHolder);
   
  } else {
   viewHolder = (ViewHolder) tag;
  }
  
  return viewHolder;
 }
 
 /**
  * ViewHolder allows us to avoid re-looking up view references
  * Since views are recycled, these references will never change
  */
 private static class ViewHolder {
  public TextView titleView;
  public TextView locationView;
 }

 
}
```

Comment: why did you set adapter to listview inside onPostResume?

Comment: then where i need to set.... i have try onCreate also it is not working

Comment: according to this post https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36927520 with api level < 16 is not allways called. So put it inside onCreate method

Comment: give me any suggestion ...where i need to set this adapter.....the issue is ..fist time the list is working when i click that postion and come back means it is not working.. the all list items are gone

Comment: set your adapter inside onCreate after adapter creation listAdapter = new CropsAdapter(this,R.layout.listview); load data and set it

Comment: sorry ...same issue.....